# Redimensionar una imagen guardada en mi servidor con Laravel-6

Tags: php, laravel, imagen, laravel-6, intervention

Tengo la url de una imagen guardada en mi servidor, pero necesito copiar la imagen que esta en es ubicacion para redimensionarla pero no se como puedo hacerlo para obtener la imagen desde el sevidor con laravel
Esta es la ubicacion en donde esta guardada la imagen
/storage/projects/100/jEAyoxFvM4lfYM5khgo3LDiPn1T5zk09WMOIg0fO.png

Instale Intervention pero no entiendo como puedo obtener la imagen intente con esto
return Image::make($project->image)->response('png');

Pero no funciona

Comment: Pero necesitas de verdad redimensionarla? Porque las imágenes puedes controlar del lado del cliente el tamaño que tengan sin necesidad de hacer ningún tipo de modificación del archivo... el propio browser se encarga de hacer la escalada... asumo que dependiendo de 1000 variables de estilo para el elemento donde la quieras mostrar.

Comment: Lo que pasa es que estoy generando un pdf con dompdf, y resulta que la imagen que esta alojada pesa 10.7 mb y todas las imagenes de mas de 6 mb me resulta error al intentar generar los pdf y se tarda tambien en hacer el trabajo. por eso pensaba en generar una copia de la imagen que ya esta alojada, reducir las dimensiones a 200 x 200 y pegarla en el pdf

Comment: Creo que es información que debería ser parte de la pregunta

Comment: Revisa el primer ejemplo de la documentación http://image.intervention.io/

Answer (score 0):

Está bien que uses Image Intervention para eso, el funcionamiento sería de esta manera:

```js
$img = Image::make($project->image); // Asegúrate de cómo tienes tu mutador para obtener la ruta correcta

//Con esto, redimensionas la imagen, manteniendo la relación de aspecto
$img->resize(200 , null, function ($constraint) {
    $constraint->aspectRatio();
});

$img->encode('jpeg'); // Opcional para darle otro formato

// De esta manera no se puede así el Storage
model->image = Storage::put('path/' . $random_name . '.jpeg', $img); // No usar así


// Por lo que hay que trabajar un poco más en eso, guardarlo y asignar la ruta manualmente
$random_name = 'randon_name';
Storage::put('path/' . $random_name . '.jpeg', $img);
$model->new_image = 'path/' . $random_name . '.jpeg';
$model->save();
```

En tu modelo, asegúrate de tener tu mutador algo así y asegúrate de haber configurado bien tu variable de `FILESYSTEM_DRIVER` en tu archivo `.env`.

La ruta que se guarda en BD para la imagen debería de ser: `projects/100/jEAyoxFvM4lfYM5khgo3LDiPn1T5zk09WMOIg0fO.png` y cuando lo llamas desde su objeto, debería de cambiar (sin modificar la BD) a: `tuapp.com/projects/100/jEAyoxFvM4lfYM5khgo3LDiPn1T5zk09WMOIg0fO.png`, esto dependiendo qué tipo de disco tienes.

También de haber configurado bien el disco que usas (el especificado en el `FILESYSTEM_DRIVER`) en el archivo `filesystems.php`.

```js
public function getImageAttribute()
{
    if ($this->attributes['image']) {
        return Storage::url($this->attributes['image']); // Dependerá de tu filesystem_driver en el .env
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Aunque a veces esta librería falla con ciertas imágenes y nunca las procesa, es buena, pero otra con la que ya he trabajado es [ImageKit](https://imagekit.io/) tiene una manera muy fácil de crear los recursos, sin instalar nada, por medio de url. Solamente tienes que configurar el acceso hacia donde tienes tus recursos, copiar un ID para usar en tus URL y listo. Esta herramienta te da 20 GB de tráfico al mes gratis y me ha fallado mucho menos que Image Intevention.

Para hacer lo anterior, lo harías de la manera:

```js
$img = file_get_contents('https://ik.imagekit.io/' . config('image_kit.id') . '/' . $project->getOriginal('image') . '?tr=w-' . $width . ',pr');

$random_name = 'randon_name';
Storage::put('path/' . $random_name . '.jpeg', $img);
$model->new_image = 'path/' . $random_name . '.jpeg';
$model->save();
```